# How to write an own resize corner/handle for an NSWindow?

Tags: cocoa, resize, nswindow, resizegrip

How can I write an own resize corner/handle for an NSWindow? I'm using a subclass of an NSWindow without the default resize corner, but I need it for my window.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic outline:

- Create a view.
- Put some "drag me" indicator appropriate to your window in the view.
- Have the view's drag action method respond by resizing the window so that the corner in question is now located at the current mouse position.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain the drag action method more? I don't know what you mean.